# When do I need to start cleaning my baby's tongue?

Tags: brushing-teeth

When do I need to start cleaning my baby's tongue?

Birth? Non-breast-milk? Solid food? Teething? Post-teething?

Comment: Why would you do that at all? I've never cleaned my own tongue, let alone my daughter's...

Comment: @Dariusz, tongue cleaning is actually a good step in oral hygiene ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue_cleaner)), yet not too common in Europe.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't normally "need" to clean your baby's tongue. Unlike with their teeth, plaque doesn't usually cause any harm on the tongue.

If your baby's breath smells fine, then you don't need to worry.

Some children never really get much plaque on their tongues. Our daughter is 6, and we've never found it necessary to clean her tongue. However with our son, we started occasionally cleaning it post 3 years, as we noticed his breath sometimes had a slight odor.

The best thing to do is avoid sugary food as much as possible, and make sure your baby gets plenty of water.

If you to try to clean your child's tongue, be very careful not to go back too far. It shouldn't be causing any discomfort to the child.